# Как в приоритетной очереди найти и удалить запись?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Можно ли реализовать в данном примере поиск и удаление одной записи?

Необходимо реализовать очередь на базе списков, применяя комбинированный алгоритм для ее обслуживания. Затем продемонстрировать выполнение основных операций с элементами очереди: поиск, добавление, удаление.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Компаратор
        Queue<Customer> customerPriorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(7, idComparator);
        add(customerPriorityQueue);
        poll(customerPriorityQueue);
    }

    //Класс компаратора
    public static Comparator<Customer> idComparator = new Comparator<Customer>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
            return (int) (c1.getId() - c2.getId());
        }
    };

    //Метод добавления элементов в очередь
    private static void add(Queue<Customer> customerPriorityQueue) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            int id = rand.nextInt(100);

            customerPriorityQueue.add(new Customer(id, "Name "+id));
        }
    }

    //Метод для обработки данных очереди
    private static void poll(Queue<Customer> customerPriorityQueue) {
        while(true){
            Customer cust = customerPriorityQueue.poll();
            if(cust == null) break;
            System.out.println("Обработка клиента с id=" + cust.getId() + " \\\\ " + cust.getName());
        }
    }
}

class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Customer(int i, String n){
        this.id=i;
        this.name=n;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: ответ на ваш вопрос - да, можно. использутйет метод `remove` или `removeIf`

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я не заметил. А поиск?

Comment: зачем вам нужно что-то искать в очереди?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Задание такое

Comment: добавьте точный вариант заданя в вопрос

Comment: @aaa вы конечно сможете вытащить поочередно элементы из очереди, тем самым произведя поиск, но потом нужно будет куда то деть эти самые элементы, либо создав для них еще одну очередь либо положив в промежуточную коллекцию и после нахождения элемента добавить их снова. В любом случае очередь не предназначена для таких операций и я вам настоятельно рекомендую рассмотреть какую нибудь другую структуру данных.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Добавил

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov зря вы так) можно много чего сделать, если аккуратно.

Comment: и кстати зря вопрос минусовали, вполне нормальный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полный ответ не пишу. Только идею.

1. добавим в хранимую структуру флаг <удалено>, значение по умолчанию ложь
2. Сделаем хеш-таблицу или что вам нравится вида <ключ> -> <структура>.
3. Для удаления используя таблицу из пункта 2, найдём сам элемент и выставим флаг удалено.
4. флаг должен либо игнорироваться при проверке на минимальность элемента (чтобы инвариант не нарушить) либо удалённый элемент может быть меньше не удалённого, но тогда нужно делать подъём в куче (кучу руками писать придётся).
5. если верхний элемент кучи (очереди) удалён, то выталкиваем (удаляем) его.
6. повторяем шаг 5.

Я думаю вы понимаете, что приоритетная очередь и куча это одно и тоже. Вам в любом случае придётся писать свою обёртку над стандартным классом (или кучи или очереди), над чем - дело вкуса, я бы предпочёл над кучей, чтобы не тянуть реализацию не нужных методов.

Сложность операции удаления - O(1) (если хеш контейнер, O(ln K) в противном случае). Остальные операции - O(ln K), где K - максимальное число элементов в очереди (зависит от реализации компаратора).

Comment: каким образом поиск занимает O(lnK), или у вас там сбалансированное бинарное дерево вместо кучи ?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а что бывает не сбалансированная куча?) А если серьёзно куча - почти полное двоичное дерево. Там только нижний слой может быть не заполнен.

Comment: заметьте я не говорил про сбалансированную кучу, я написал про бинарное дерево. А куча это совсем не дерево, у нее другой инвариант. И найти в ней элемент за логарифм не представляется возможным.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov перечитайте пункт 2. Там вообще 1 операция будет.

Comment: чем ваш вариант лучше использования TreeMap ?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov быстрее. В TreeMap скрытая константа на балансировку есть. Тут всё сразу проходит. Да и память не сегментируется совсем (это один цельный блок). Можно легко на массив запихать. Можно конечно и красно-чёрное делать, но я лично его сам писать наизусть не рискну. Кучу напишу минут за 5. Обычно ничего не даётся бесплатно. И за то что у нас есть избыточная полностью упорядоченная структура мы платим скоростью (меньше) и памятью (больше).